# How to open locally saved files on cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova application, which is caching a few files in the local file system, which I suppose is working (because on ios there are no problems at all and on android I can see the cached images).

The problem is, when I want to display the PDF files on android (no matter if I use the inappbrowser plugin or cordova-plugin-file-opener2) the external window opens shortly and closes then immediatelly.
In Android studio I get the following error message: 
`E/Surface getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x96b20cc0`

If you search about that error, you get many posts about permission problems. But I dont know which permission I could need.

Here is how I am opening the pdf files:

```
window.open("file:/// .... ", "_system");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was changing the data directory in the cordova-plugin-file it was working:

[Cordova open local Pdf file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246357/cordova-open-local-pdf-file-on-android)